# Return true from object only when all of its children are truthy

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object that can sometimes return properties (or Immutable.map) as undefined.

`(2) [Map, undefined]`

I'd like for this parent object to be a boolean of true only when both items are Maps. Currently,

`let hasLocation = Lodash.overEvery(obj.mapData.toArray())`

and then later

`hasLocation(2)`

seems to be the best option but only seems to return true when both are undefined and examples of `overEvery` seem to be very thin on the ground. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need lodash:

```
const noUndefineds = hasLocation.every(item => item !== undefined);
```

If you know that only the `undefined`s would be falsey, you can shorten to:

```
const noUndefineds = hasLocation.every(Boolean); // all items are truthy values.
```

Comment: v.spicy second snippet!